# this python code for drowsiness detection system prints multiple output

Tags: python, twilio-api, dlib

i'm working on a project which raises an alert if the score goes above 15 and will send the message to the registered number is the score goes above 100. The score is calculated based on how long the user's eyes are closed. I'm using following libraries and tools

1. Dlib
2. Opencv
3. Spicy.spatial
4. Pygames
5. shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat file
6. Twilio Api - for sending messages
7. Ipstack APi - for getting users current location

Below is the code i'm using

detect.py:

```
import cv2
import dlib
from scipy.spatial import distance
import pygame
import subprocess 

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
ret, frame = cap.read()
height,width = frame.shape[:2]
font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX_SMALL
Score = 0
cv2.rectangle(frame, (0,height-50) ,(200,height) , (0,0,0) , thickness=cv2.FILLED )

# INITIALIZING THE MIXER SO THAT
# ALERT AUDIO MESSAGE CAN BE DELIVERED
pygame.mixer.init()
pygame.mixer.music.load("alarm.wav")

# SETTING UP OF CAMERA TO 1 YOU CAN
# EVEN CHOOSE 0 IN PLACE OF 1


# FACE DETECTION OR MAPPING THE FACE TO
# GET THE Eye AND EYES DETECTED
face_detector = dlib.get_frontal_face_detector()

# PUT THE LOCATION OF .DAT FILE (FILE FOR
# PREDECTING THE LANDMARKS ON FACE )
dlib_facelandmark = dlib.shape_predictor(
"C:\\Users\\DELL\\Documents\\Project_TYCS\\shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat")

# FUNCTION CALCULATING THE ASPECT RATIO FOR
# THE Eye BY USING EUCLIDEAN DISTANCE FUNCTION
def Detect_Eye(eye):
    poi_A = distance.euclidean(eye[1], eye[5])
    poi_B = distance.euclidean(eye[2], eye[4])
    poi_C = distance.euclidean(eye[0], eye[3])
    aspect_ratio_Eye = (poi_A+poi_B)/(2*poi_C)
    return aspect_ratio_Eye


# MAIN LOOP IT WILL RUN ALL THE UNLESS AND
# UNTIL THE PROGRAM IS BEING KILLED BY THE USER
while True:
    null, frame = cap.read()
    gray_scale = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces = face_detector(gray_scale)
    for face in faces:
        face_landmarks = dlib_facelandmark(gray_scale, face)
        leftEye = []
        rightEye = []

        # THESE ARE THE POINTS ALLOCATION FOR THE
        # LEFT EYES IN .DAT FILE THAT ARE FROM 42 TO 47
        for n in range(42, 48):
            x = face_landmarks.part(n).x
            y = face_landmarks.part(n).y
            rightEye.append((x, y))
            next_point = n+1
            if n == 47:
                next_point = 42
            x2 = face_landmarks.part(next_point).x
            y2 = face_landmarks.part(next_point).y
            cv2.line(frame, (x, y), (x2, y2), (0, 255, 0), 1)

        # THESE ARE THE POINTS ALLOCATION FOR THE
        # RIGHT EYES IN .DAT FILE THAT ARE FROM 36 TO 41
        for n in range(36, 42):
            x = face_landmarks.part(n).x
            y = face_landmarks.part(n).y
            leftEye.append((x, y))
            next_point = n+1
            if n == 41:
                next_point = 36
            x2 = face_landmarks.part(next_point).x
            y2 = face_landmarks.part(next_point).y
            cv2.line(frame, (x, y), (x2, y2), (255, 255, 0), 1)

        # CALCULATING THE ASPECT RATIO FOR LEFT
        # AND RIGHT EYE
        right_Eye = Detect_Eye(rightEye)
        left_Eye = Detect_Eye(leftEye)
        Eye_Rat = (left_Eye+right_Eye)/2

        # NOW ROUND OF THE VALUE OF AVERAGE MEAN
        # OF RIGHT AND LEFT EYES
        Eye_Rat2 = round(Eye_Rat,2)

        # THIS VALUE OF 0.25 (YOU CAN EVEN CHANGE IT)
        # WILL DECIDE WHETHER THE PERSONS'S EYES ARE CLOSE OR NOT
        if Eye_Rat2 < 0.25:
            Score+=1
        else : 
            Score=0           
            # CALLING THE AUDIO FUNCTION OF TEXT TO
            # AUDIO FOR ALERTING THE PERSON
        if Score > 100:

            # Call the call.py script using subprocess
            subprocess.call(['python', 'Main.py'])
            
            # Draw a rectangle and display the drowsiness alert message
            cv2.rectangle(frame, (0,0), (450, 60), (21, 56, 210), -1)
            cv2.putText(frame, "HIGHLY DROWSY, MESSAGE IS BEING SENT", (10, 40), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (255, 255, 255), 2)
            
            # Display the current score and stop message
            cv2.putText(frame, 'Score:'+str(Score), (10,height-40), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 1.5, (21, 56, 212), 1, cv2.LINE_AA) 
            cv2.putText(frame, 'Press X to stop', (500,height-450), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 0.5, (255,0,0), 1, cv2.LINE_AA)
            
            # Play the alert sound if it's not already playing
            if pygame.mixer.music.get_busy() == False:
                pygame.mixer.music.play()
            else:
                True    
                
        elif Score > 15:
            # Draw a rectangle and display the drowsiness alert message
            cv2.rectangle(frame, (0,0), (450, 60), (21, 56, 210), -1)
            cv2.putText(frame, "DROWSINESS DETECTED | ALERT! WAKE UP", (10, 40), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (255, 255, 255), 2)
            
            # Display the current score and stop message
            cv2.putText(frame, 'Score:'+str(Score), (10,height-40), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 1.5, (21, 56, 212), 1, cv2.LINE_AA) 
            cv2.putText(frame, 'Press X to stop', (500,height-450), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 0.5, (255,0,0), 1, cv2.LINE_AA)
            
            # Play the alert sound if it's not already playing
            if pygame.mixer.music.get_busy() == False:
                pygame.mixer.music.play()
            else:
                True
        else:
            # Reset the score to zero and display the current score and stop message
            score = 0
            cv2.putText(frame, 'Score:'+str(Score), (10,height-40), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 1.5, (255,255,255), 1, cv2.LINE_AA)
            cv2.putText(frame, 'Press X to stop', (500,height-450), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 0.5, (255,0,0), 1, cv2.LINE_AA)
            
            # Stop the alert sound if it's currently playing
            pygame.mixer.music.stop()

    cv2.imshow("Drowsiness DETECTOR IN OPENCV2", frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(9) & 0xFF == ord('x'):
        break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Main.py (it contains the twilio api code)

```
from twilio.rest import Client 
import Keys 
from Geo import latitude
from Geo import longitude 

Client = Client(Keys.account_sid, Keys.auth_token)

message = Client.messages.create(
    body = "**ALERT THE DRIVER IS DETECTED DROWSY OVER THE LIMIT** "+"\n"+"Live location link: "+"https://www.google.com/maps/place/"+str(latitude-0.003923)+','+str(longitude-0.003219),
    from_=Keys.twilio_number,
    to = Keys.my_phone_number
)

print(message.body)
```

Along with them i'm also using GEO.py and keys.py.

**Problem** - When the score goes above 100, in the output i just want a single message to be sent to the registered phone, but it sends multiple messages. Also the output windows also gets lagged / stuck.

[image]

I need it to only send one message if the goes above 100. i tried adding time.sleep but it dint work.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)